# Aptana Studio 3 not finding gems with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to use Aptana Studio 3 on a Ruby project I'm working on. I'm on Mac OS X 10.8, and have Ruby installed with RVM.

When I try and execute a .rb file in Aptana Studio, it gives me errors as follows:

```
/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- resque (LoadError)
    from /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/.../q_test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

From within the Aptana Studio 3 Terminal, when I type

```
rvm gemset list
```

I can see that the right version of ruby is selected, but it seems Aptana is disregarding the gemset?

What's going on? Can anybody help?

**Update**

I suspect the issue to be something to do with this:

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3306-switching-rvm-ruby-and-gemsets-on-fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to define a [default gemset](https://rvm.io/gemsets/using/) with the **--default** option

```
rvm 1.9.2-p320
rvm gemset create rails_gemset
rvm --default use ruby-1.9.2-p320@rails_gemset
```

Maybe this helps?

BTW, I would recommend to use simple editors such as Sublime Text, Textmate or Emacs instead of Aptana Studio. They are faster, leaner and neater than the big bloated IDEs (which are needed for Java, but not for Ruby).

Comment: Most helpful, thanks. I'm posting a bug report to Aptana Studio 3, one shouldn't need to do change the default to get a gemset working.